# getElementById returning null when trying to access component from customElement

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, custom-element

i created my own component that contains 2 inputs(type: range, number). I want to hide one of them after another checkbox is clicked but getElementById is returning null.

Error

[image]

This is in one js file

```
customElements.define("my-component",MyComponent);

document.getElementById('check').addEventListener("click", hideComponent, false); 

function hideComponent() {
    if(document.getElementById('check').checked) {
        document.getElementById('inp').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slider').style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('inp').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('slider').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This is my custom Element

```
export class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        wrapper.setAttribute("class","wrapper");

        const slider = wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
        slider.setAttribute("class","slider");
        slider.setAttribute("type","range");
        slider.setAttribute("id","slider");
        let minVal = this.hasAttribute("min-val")  ? this.getAttribute("min-val") : "0";
        let maxVal = this.hasAttribute("max-val")  ? this.getAttribute("max-val") : "5";
        slider.setAttribute("min",minVal);
        slider.setAttribute("max",maxVal);
        slider.setAttribute("value",minVal);

        const ampInput = wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
        ampInput.setAttribute("type","number");
        ampInput.setAttribute("id","inp");
        ampInput.setAttribute("value","5");

        const style = document.createElement("style");
        style.textContent = `.slider{
            backround: #cfc;
        }

        .inp{
            display: block;
        }

        .wrapper {
            display: inline-grid;
        }`;

        this.shadowRoot.append(style,wrapper);
```

I added style in my custom Element so i dont understand this error. What should i change to make it work ? Or how differently should i hide the element when checkbox is clicked ?

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try console logging the document.getElementById('inp') and see what would happen. if it works then the problem could be that the function is being triggered before the document is ready, which results in a null.

try wrapping it like this and see what happens

```
if (window){
 if(document.getElementById('check').checked) {
        document.getElementById('inp').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slider').style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('inp').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('slider').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Console log printed null you are right but the window didnt help... i dont think the function is triggered before document is ready because i call it after i click on checkox so  everything should be loaded already, no ?

Comment: yes you're right, i might have gotten confused there. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` does **not** give you access to DOM content *inside* shadowRoots.

If you have an `mode:open` shadowRoot you could do:

`document.querySelector("element-name").shadowRoot.document.getElementById`

But that is too verbose, and tight coupling components.

---

Since `:host-context` isn't supported in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=host-context

You can use CSS properties:

```html
<h1>range:</h1>
<my-input type="range" min="10" max="20"></my-input>
<h1>number:</h1>
<my-input type="number"></my-input>

<template id="MY-INPUT">
  <style>
    :host([type="range"]) {
      --range_display: none;
      --number_display: inline-block;
    }
    :host([type="number"]) {
      --range_display: inline-block;
      --number_display: none;
    }
    [type="range"] {
      display: var(--range_display);
    }
    [type="number"] {
      display: var(--number_display);
    }
  </style>
  <input type="range"><input type="number">
</template>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-input', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
       .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
       .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      let range = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('[type="range"]');
      let number = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('[type="number"]');
            //... configure here
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: First method with query selector did not work... im getting error the last function getElementById is not defined. And with the code i dont get what should this do ? Could you describe it more and how should i use with my problem ?

Comment: You are not posting the relevant parts of your code. Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)